# Modelling 1-D expanding-accelerating space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, mathematical-modeling

I am writing physics engine in C++ and I am stuck on advanced math problem.

I need equation that allows me update the position of a moving point in 1-D expanding and accelerating space.

Just good old number on x-axis, that is interpreted as position of the point, relative to 0 (beginning). //any non-expanding units will work

Now the trick, is that the point is moving and the space (1D-line) is continuously  being stretched. The expansion is completely smooth - not quantized (but I think we can use quantized version of this problem and using limit or other tool, converge on the continuous solution.

The input for the equation are these variables: velocity of the point, velocity of the initial expansion,
acceleration of the expansion.

Output is just position of the point on the X axis.

//small suggestion on the solution
Lets make our units for this problem, imagine point 2. on same x-axis that is also moving, but doesnt experience the expansion of space (just for the sake of argument). We can set the distance of point 2. as `1` for making custom unit and refrence the expanding point 1 position as multiple of distance of point 2 from the beginning (still no stretching happens in points 2 frame of refrence, the track doesnt expand, nor does the positon 2 velocity change)

//just question
Can the solution be expanded by higher distance displacement time-derivatives ?

If you solve this, you are wizard by my standarts. I have met people like this in my life and they are always fascinating to me. Thank you all

Comment: The big question that you need to answer is "Do the units on the x axis expand together with the space?" What I mean, what's the meaning of one unit? Do you measure this distance in a "fixed" reference frame, or in the reference frame of the stretching space. Additionally, is the velocity of the point measured in the "fixed" or "stretching" reference frame?

Comment: The units I have proposed get rid of this problem, because they are expressed as ratio.

Comment: Remember, the distance travelled is not dependant on the coordinate system. It is finite numerical value and it is expressed in non-expanding units.

Comment: But I can see better now, there might be ambiguity, because the distance can be expressed in expanding units as well, so I apologize for the ambiguity.

Comment: The dream output would be function that has the same derivative as the time-derivative of displacement of point 1 in above analogy. This function will be smooth and monotonic and completely in first function quadrant.

Comment: I will feed the function with "time quanta" (basically integer "1")  and the position on x-axis will update accordingly to the expansion and acceleration of space. The time quanta counter (number of time increments) will evolve (in other words: update) the state of the point 1.